# Converting a day and a year to a date in VBScript

Tags: datetime, vbscript

I've seen a few similar questions/answers, but none of them answered my question/answered for VBS. I have a set of days that I would like to convert to dates for this year. However, when I try to convert them to dates, I get the wrong values because it uses the year 1900. Is there some way I can specify the year in the CDate function? I looked at the [Calendar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.calendar(v=vs.110).aspx) class, but that didn't apply because I'm using VBScript.

```
MsgBox(CDate(195))
MsgBox(CDate(196))
MsgBox(CDate(197))
MsgBox(CDate(198))
MsgBox(CDate(199))
```

These give me 7/13/1900, 7/14/1900, 7/15/1900, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [DateAdd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cb7z8yf9%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) to add a number of days to a start date obtained by [DateSerial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1we4t8hy%28v=vs.84%29.aspx):

```
>> dt2014 = DateSerial(2014, 1, 1)
>> WScript.Echo dt2014
>>
01.01.2014
>> WScript.Echo DateAdd("d", 195, dt2014)
>>
15.07.2014
```

(German locale; lookout for a +-1 bias (adding to the first day of year))

Update wrt to @Bond's comment:

Even if you need to add many days to on start date (as I understood the task), using just DateSerial with many different day-parameters may well be more efficient.

Comment: You can also just plug the day directly into `DateSerial` to avoid the +1 issue. Just use a month of January: `dt = DateSerial(2014, 1, 195) ==> 2014.07.14`